# Magento Adminpanel - Custom Grid Error on Filter

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I have created a custom Grid in the adminpanel where i need to show orders and the last comment for the order. I did this by adding Join in the `_prepareCollection function` and the data is showing properly.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $subquery = new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT parent_id,MAX(entity_id) as comment_id,created_at as comment_date,comment FROM sales_flat_order_status_history GROUP BY parent_id ORDER BY `sales_flat_order_status_history`.`parent_id` DESC)');
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('c'=>$subquery), 'c.parent_id = main_table.entity_id', array('c.*'));
        //echo $collection->getSelect();exit;
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

However if i try to filter the comment column its showing following error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comment' in 'where clause'
```

What i'm missing. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: would you give me final query with comment filter  ??

Comment: Do you want me to print the raw query? This is what i get when i print it SELECT `main_table`.*, `c`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN (SELECT parent_id,MAX(entity_id) as comment_id,created_at as comment_date,comment FROM sales_flat_order_status_history GROUP BY parent_id ORDER BY `sales_flat_order_status_history`.`parent_id` DESC) AS `c` ON c.parent_id = main_table.entity_id

Comment: above query working fine for me

Comment: provide code and query that you are trying for filter in comment

Comment: This is the query that i get when i do echo echo $collection->getSelect(); in _prepareCollection(); But i think the actual error is triggered in this file /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php

Comment: Thanks for the replays @MurtuzaZabuawala. I have found a solution for the issue and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for the issue. We need to call custom function for filter for custom columns This is done by as follows.

```
$this->addColumn('comment', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Comment'),
            'index' => 'comment',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this,'filterComment'),
        ));

public function filterComment($collection, $column) {

        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $collection->getSelect()->where(
        "c.comment like ?", "%$value%");
        return $this;
    }
```